# Factorial Function in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

So I'm trying to create a factorial function in assembler

In c:

```
 #include<stdio.h>



int fat (int n) 
{
      if (n==0) return 1;
      else return n*fat(n-1);
}

    int main (void){

    printf("%d\n", fat(4));
       return 0;

    }
```

In Assembly:

```
.text

.global    fat
fat:push    %ebp   
    mov    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $1,%eax
    movl    4(%ebp),%edx

LOOP:cmp    $0,%edx
    je FIM
    sub    $1,%edx
    push    %edx
    call    fat
    imul    %edx,%eax

FIM:mov    %ebp, %esp
    pop    %ebp
    ret
```

I keep getting the segmentation fault error and I don't know why...can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you calculate factorial recursively? Did you think about the loop?

Comment: @ymorenz uh, what ASM compiler is this for?

Comment: @Link this is GAS, mostly used by linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset is probably wrong in this line:

```
movl    4(%ebp),%edx
```

The stack has the previous value of `%ebp` and the return address already, so your offset is going to have to be more than 4.

I recommend stepping through the assembly code with the debugger, and make sure that all the register values are exactly what you expect them to be. You will also have problems with the `%edx` register across calls unless you save and restore its value, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
fat:push    %ebp   
    mov    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $1,%eax
    movl    4(%ebp),%edx /* Must be 8(%ebp) because of the return address! */

LOOP:cmp    $0,%edx
    je FIM
    sub    $1,%edx
    push    %edx
    call    fat /* The call to fat() just trashed edx, oops. Gotta save/restore it! */
    imul    %edx,%eax /* The result will be in edx, but you need to return it in eax! */
    /* Why isn't "push %edx" compensated here with "pop" or "addl $4,%esp"??? */
FIM:mov    %ebp, %esp
    pop    %ebp
    ret
```

Rewriting your C function, assemblyish style, may be helpful:

```
int fat (int n) 
{
    int eax, edx, savedEdx;

    eax = 1;
    edx = n; /* n = %8(%ebp) */
    if (edx == 0)
      goto done;

    savedEdx = edx; /* can do this with pushl %edx */
    --edx;
    eax = fat(edx); /* pushl %edx; call fat; addl $4, %esp or popl %edx */
    edx = savedEdx; /* popl %edx */

    eax *= edx; /* can do this with imul %edx */

done:
    return eax;
}
```

Comment: the result of the multiplication will be in EDX:EAX, not just EAX

Comment: @coolbartek Look up the CPU manual. IMUL with 2 operands works in a different way compared to MUL or IMUL with 1 operand. Quote: `IMUL r32, r/m32: doubleword register ← doubleword register ∗ r/m32.` What you're saying is valid for IMUL with 1 operand, quote from the same page in the manual: `IMUL r/m32: EDX:EAX ← EAX ∗ r/m32.`

Comment: you are correct, thanks for pointing that out, that sounds like an overflow for most operations though

Comment: @coolbartek Well, you have gazillions of such overflows in C and C++, where `int`*`int` produces `int`. :)